# Como setar o valor de um elemento usando jquery e condicionalmente setando um valor manual se o valor for vazio

Tags: jquery

Tenho um formulário, que ao ser submetido, envia dados para uma janela modal. 
Uma parte do jquery que tenho, pega o valor enviado pelo textbox com id "diagnostico" e passa este valor para a janela modal, numa tag span com id "modal_diagnostico", como mostrado na linha abaixo:

$("#modal_diagnostico").text($("#diagnostico").val());

Eu preciso passar um texto fixo, caso o valor do texbox "diagnostico" esteja vazio (algo como "Não informado"), e infelizmente não sei como fazer isso. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: tentei      if(text($("#diagnostico").val().length !== 0){
        $("#modal_diagnostico").text($("#diagnostico").val());
    }
    else
    { $("#modal_diagnostico").text("TESTE".val());
        
    } mas sem sucesso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou te mostrar duas técnicas (das inumeras) para fazer isso,
uma tradicional com if e else

```
var texto = $("#diagnostico").val();
if(texto != "")
   $("#modal_diagnostico").text( texto );
else
   $("#modal_diagnostico").text( "Texto estático" );
```

Agora operadores ternários (que basicamente faz a mesma coisa nesse exemplo)

```
$("#modal_diagnostico").text( ($("#diagnostico").val()) ? $("#diagnostico").val() : "Texto estático" );
```